# How to pull in full requests library during python setup.py install

Tags: python

When I install a brand new version of ubuntu 14.04, I can see requests 2.2.1 is already there as a python package.  The only problem is it doesn't contain urllib3 which I need.  if I install another other version of requests, including 2.1 or 2.3, I get what I want.

any clues are to why?  maybe this is a know problem in 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

So if I get it right: you are comfortable with the version of `requests` installed in Ubuntu 14.04 by default, but you need `urllib3`.
If this is right then you should just install `urllib3` with `pip`:

```
pip install urllib3
```